# Why is there no error when requesting interface data?

Tags: reactjs

I defined an interface, I know that when I use literals to declare an object as this interface type.
If the field is not correct, it will report an error.

When I request data from the background interface,I assign this data to a variable that has been declared as an interface type.It did not report an error.

I guess it may be that typescript can't process data from the future.
But why is it not giving an error?For example, res.data can't find content/id.

My English is not very good, it may not be very clear, if I can't understand it, I will explain it as much as possible.

````
```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getMsgList } from '../api';

interface Props {
  visible: boolean;
}

interface demo {
  id: number;
  content: string;
}

const Template: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState<demo[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.visible !== visible) {
      setVisible(props.visible);
      getData();
    }
  }, [props.visible, visible]);

  const getData = () => {
    getMsgList()
      .then(res=>{
        // res.data - structure
        // [{
        //   id: number;
        //   content: string;
        //   created_at: string;
        //   user: {
        //     username: string;
        //   }
        // }]
        setDataList(res.data)
        // After this assignment,The dataList field exceeds the description of the demo interface.

      })
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {dataList}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Template;

```
````

Comment: The type system from TypeScript only exists *at compile time*, it does not exist *at runtime*. So, if at runtime you are getting data that doesn't match what you've described, then TypeScript cannot actually account for it.

Comment: @VLAZ
Thank you for your answer, this is consistent with my guess.
I just started using typescript. It’s strange to behave like this.
I thought it would throw an error that xxx does not exist on res.data.